# PhpStorm. Перемещение файлов с изменением namespace

Tags: php, phpstorm, namespace

Здравствуйте.

Слышал, что можно перемещать файлы в PhpStorm между папками с автоматическим изменением namespace в файле, и везде, где он упоминается.

Информации не нашел даже на jetBrains. Возможно вы подскажете как именно это сделать?

версия 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все, разобрался. Оказывается нужно было перемещать не файлы, а классы.

Выделяем класс, нажимаем F6, и вводим новый namespace. Тогда все упоминания о нем будут изменены во всем проекте.

Comment: здорово =) пхпшторм - реально сильная штука... пересел на него с нетбинса: в начале было очень непривычно... а сейчас - здорово! )))